# Get Stage View Times for Current Build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to get the stage view time values programatically? [image: stage view times]

I would like to print within the console the stage times for all the stages including the stage titles.

Something like:

```
Build Code: 19s
Unit Tests: 7s
Integration Tests: 17s
```

Looking at the plugin code I can see how it's rendered through the formatter, but I can't figure out how I could access those values through a Jenkinsfile.

In the source code it looks like millisecond time is being used. I can convert that easily to better human readable time.

```
/**
 * Calculate how long something took from start to end
 * @param start Start time in milliseconds
 * @param end   End Time in milliseconds
 * @return  Duration as String from start to end
 */
def calculateDuration(start, end) {
    long elapsedTime = end - start

    Long second = (elapsedTime / 1000).longValue() % 60;
    Long minute = (elapsedTime / (1000 * 60)).longValue() % 60;
    Long hour = (elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)).longValue() % 24;
    Long remainderMillis = elapsedTime % 1000

    return "${hour}h ${minute}m ${second}s ${remainderMillis}ms"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't going to be the super easy solution you're looking for, but I didn't know how to do this either and wanted to try.

Basically I'm writing simple HTML to a file at the OS level, and at the end publishing it via the **Rich Text Publisher** plugin. It then displays on the build page.

I'm not sure how to properly format the duration into hh:mm:ss

[image]

```
def logit(logMessage) {
    logFile.append(logMessage + "\n")
}

def calculateDuration(start, end) {
    long elapsedTime = end - start

    Long second = (elapsedTime / 1000).longValue() % 60;
    Long minute = (elapsedTime / (1000 * 60)).longValue() % 60;
    Long hour = (elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)).longValue() % 24;
    Long remainderMillis = elapsedTime % 1000

    return "${hour}h ${minute}m ${second}s ${remainderMillis}ms"
}

node () {
    stage('Create logfile') {
       sh "rm -f /tmp/log.html"
       logFile = new File("/tmp/log.html")
       logit("<html>")
       logit("  <body>")
    }
    stage('Time this stage') {
       start = System.currentTimeMillis()
       logit("Start time " + start + "<br>")
       sleep(3)
       end = System.currentTimeMillis()
       logit("End time " + end + "<br>")
       dur = calculateDuration(start, end)
       println "Duration: " + dur
       logit("Duration: " + dur + "<br>")
    }
    stage('Publish') {
       logit("  </body>")
       logit("</html>")
       rtp (nullAction: '1', stableText: '${FILE:/tmp/log.html}')
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of painful. I was trying to avoid going through HTML or making REST calls and then parsing that. However since you took the time, I updated my original question with a method that can make the time more human readable, so you can use it if you want ;)

Comment: Also if you are doing that much work, might as well do a `start = System.currentMillis()` right before the stage declaration and when it ends. I was hoping to not have to add that in every stage making the code more verbose for a minor stylistic benefit

Comment: Yep I hear you on the pain. Seems like there ought to be an easy way to do this, I've got some jobs with a dozen stages over the course of hours, it would be really handy info to have displayed, and also sent out after the fact. Thanks very much for the update!

Comment: Two years later I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, years later I have discovered a better solution that gives me exactly what I needed, which was the time by stage.

Depending on the type of Jenkins job, Freeestyle or Multibranch you can look at the exposed Jenkins API endpoints to get the information.

Freestyle Endpoint: `env.BUILD_URL/api/json?pretty=true`

Multibranch endpoint: `env.BUILD_URL/wfapi/describe`

It's a JSON response, so it's easy to parse and store by using `readJSON` Jenkins DSL.

Below you can see an example response for a freestyle job. Sorry for the blackout but didn't want to expose corporate dir structures.
[image]